# onPreCreate with Owner pulled from external source

Tags: javascript, rally

I am in the process of trying to create a custom HTML app in Rally to have a User Story created through the Add New component and drawing on data from an external source using JQuery with YQL JSON query.

This process works a wonder for pre-filled name, description and notes. However, the only way at the moment Owner works pre-filled is using an Object Dropdown to manually select the user. I want to be able to pull the Owner from the same external source.

Presently this is dummy code to test the theory:

```
var statement = "select * from html where url='" + value + "' and xpath='//h1'";
        document.getElementById('statement').innerHTML = statement;
        $.queryYQL(statement, "json", function (data) {
            var item = data.query.results.h1;  
            for(var i=0;i<item.length;i++){  
                title = item[i].content; 
                style = item[i].style;
                output += "<h3>"+title +"<br />"+ style +"</h3>"; 
            }
            document.getElementById('results').innerHTML = output;   
        });

function onAddNewPreCreate(addNew, eventArgs) {
        eventArgs.item["Name"] = title;
        eventArgs.item["Description"] = output;
        eventArgs.item["Notes"] = style;
        eventArgs.item["Owner"] = user;
    }
```

The 'value' variable is set via a textbox where the user can input the URL of where they want to grab the external data from.

The user variable is set via the dropdown. I have tried replacing the user variable with the exact same display name as the user in Rally such as eventArgs.item["Owner"] = "User Name"; but this results in a blank for the Owner of the User Story when created.

Any ideas on how this may be achieved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since Users are objects in Rally, you cannot set an Artifact's Owner attribute to be the string of a Rally username, rather, you must set the Owner to be a Reference to a valid Rally User, in the form of a ref: `/user/12345678910` where the long integer is the Object ID of the User of interest. You can use the rallyDataSource and AppSDK to do a query on the string value of the Rally User Name, and obtain the needed ref.

I've included a basic example that illustrates the idea of taking an e-mail formatted User Name, and querying Rally for the reference to the needed User object. The example uses a simple DOM `<select>` component to simulate an "external" source of username data (in your case populated via JQuery with YQL JSON). The examples does this in lieu of the AppSDK ObjectDropdown, which although the simplest way to accomplish this, as you note doesn't suit your needs since you are polling an external source as the source of your user-selector.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<!-- Copyright (c) 2011 Rally Software Development Corp. All rights reserved -->
<html>
<head>
    <title>Component Example: Add New User Story, &quotExternal&quot User Chooser</title>
    <meta name="Name" content="Component Example: Add New User Story, 'External' User Chooser" />
    <meta name="Version" content="2012.1" />
    <meta name="Vendor" content="Rally Labs" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://rally1.rallydev.com/apps/1.26/sdk.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

      // Global variables to store Reference to selected User
      var userRef = null;
      var rallyDataSource;

    var getUserRef = function(results) {      
        var user = results.users[0];
        userRef = user._ref;
    };

    function userSelectChanged() {

        var userChooser = document.getElementById("userChooser");
        var strUser = userChooser.options[userChooser.selectedIndex].value;

        queryString = '(UserName = "' + strUser + '")';

        var userQueryConfig = { 
          type : 'user',
          key : 'users',
          fetch: 'UserName,DisplayName,Role',
          query: queryString
        };

        rallyDataSource.findAll(userQueryConfig, getUserRef);
    }

    function onAddNewAdd(addNew, eventArgs){      
        var createdItem = eventArgs.item;
        var createdFormattedId = createdItem.FormattedID;       
        alert("Created new User Story with Formatted ID: " + createdFormattedId);
    }

    function onAddNewPreCreate(addNew, eventArgs)
    {
        // Grab Rally ref of User selected in HTML dropdown
        // set it as Owner attribute of created User Story
        eventArgs.item["Owner"] = userRef;
    }
    function onLoad() {

        rallyDataSource = new rally.sdk.data.RallyDataSource('__WORKSPACE_OID__',
                '__PROJECT_OID__',
                '__PROJECT_SCOPING_UP__',
                '__PROJECT_SCOPING_DOWN__');

        var addNewConfig = {
           types : ["HierarchicalRequirement"]
        };

        // Populate userRef from Rally for default selected user:
        userSelectChanged();

        var addNew = new rally.sdk.ui.AddNewArtifact(addNewConfig, rallyDataSource);
        addNew.addEventListener("onAdd",onAddNewAdd);
        addNew.addEventListener('onPreCreate', onAddNewPreCreate);
        addNew.display("addNewDiv");


    }

    rally.addOnLoad(onLoad);

    </script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="addNewDiv"></div>
<div id="userChooserDiv">
Select a Rally User as Story Owner:
<select id="userChooser" onChange="userSelectChanged()">
  <option selected value="user1@company.com">user1@company.com</option>
  <option value="user2@company.com">user2@company.com</option>
  <option value="user3@company.com">user3@company.com</option>
</select>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi @Markw.
Your solution is great.
Thanks heaps!